# migrating a website to WIKI

Tags: html, wiki

We have a intranet that we have lots of html pages and attachments (.doc, .xls, etc) and we are looking to migrating this to confluence WIKI.  Doesn't anyone know of any script or anything that can be used to automate this process as we dont want to do it by hand ideally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check [How can I import HTML pages?](http://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=151106) in the confluence importing faq? there are some options, including a Data Conversion Service company specialised in converting large websites into Confluence. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[This online tool](http://toolserver.org/~diberri/cgi-bin/html2wiki/) knows a lot of wiki syntaxes.